# Обработка действий пользователя во всплывающем окне

Tags: xcode, ios

хочу сделать при переходе из одного ViewController'a в другой под управлением TabBarController'a всплывающее окошко с сообщением и ждущее действий пользователя. в зависимости от правильности действий дается доступ к следующему окну или отмена перехода.
реализацию хочу сделать не по кнопкам а по жестам, поскольку приложение для детей.

все что пришло пока в голову - это использовать alertView

```
//создаем окошко диалога
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Настройки"
                                   message: msg
                                  delegate: self
                         cancelButtonTitle: nil
                         otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

мои попытки обработать нажатия проходят только по закрытию алерта во втором ViewController'e. сижу полдня, не могу разобраться что делать дальше. возможно ли сделать в алерте обработку жестов? если нет, то в каком направление мне копать, чтобы разобраться с данной темой.

спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте свои сабвьюхи на UIAlerView нагуглил тут несколько ответов как это делается https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7